# topology homework

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I'm new to topology, and therefore not very good at it yet. I have following questions, that I have ansewer, please help me verify what is not correct and what is missing in my answers.

1. Let $X$ be a set and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a function. Define 
   $$d: X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$$
   State which properties $f$ must fulfill in order to $d$ be a metric, and prove that they are necessary and sufficient.

my answer:

$f$ must fulfil

M1:
$$d(f(x),f(y))=|f(x)-f(y)|=0\iff f(x)=f(y)$$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=0\Rightarrow f(x)-f(y)=0\iff f(x)=f(y)$$
and the other way around 
$$f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y))=|f(x)-f(y)|=|0|=0$$

M2:
$$d(f(x),f(y))=|f(x)-f(y)|=|-(f(y)-f(x))|=|f(y)-f(x)|=d(f(y),f(x))$$

M3:
$$d(x,y)≤d(x,z)+d(z,y)$$
$$d(f(x),f(y))=|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(z)+f(z)-f(y)|≤|f(x)-f(z)|+|f(z)-f(y)|=d(f(x),f(z))+d(f(z),f(y))$$

1. Prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=1+1/a_n$   for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric, and determine afterwards its limit. Can you interpret the limit geometrically?

my answer:

$$d(x_{n+1},x_n )≤1/2\quad d(x_n,x_{n-1} )\Rightarrow d(x_n,x_m )≤(1/2)^{n+m-1} d(x_1,x_0 )$$

We know that $(1/2)^{n+m-1}$ goes against 0, so $d(x_n,x_m )$ goes against 0 too, therefore we have to find the limit.
If exact converge will $a_n\rightarrow a, a_{n+1}\rightarrow a$ goes against same number:

$$a=1+1/a$$
$$a=(√5+1)/2  og-(√5-1)/2$$

1. Prove that $S\subset\mathbb {R}$ it holds inf(S) = -sup(-S), where $-S=\{-s:s\in S\}$.

My answer:

We know $inf⁡(S)≤s$ for all $s$. Therefore $-inf⁡(S)≥s$. In other words, $-inf⁡(S)$ is an upper bound for $–S$. Hence, $sup⁡(-S)≤-inf⁡(S)⟹inf⁡(S)≤-sup⁡(-S)$. This is half of the problem. But with this in mind, you can figure out the other direction. In other words you want to show $inf⁡(S)≥-sup⁡(-S)$. So you can say that since $-S$ is bounded above, then $-s≤sup⁡(-S)⟹s ≥-sup⁡(-S)$. Therefore, $-sup⁡(-S)$ is a lower bound for $S$ which implies $inf⁡(S)≥-sup⁡(-S)$.
Finally $inf⁡(S)≤-sup⁡(-S)$ and $inf⁡(S)≥-sup⁡(-S)$ implies 
$inf⁡(S)=-sup⁡(-S).$

Comment: sorry first question was: Let X be a set and f:X→R..., the one written  under

Comment: Use "edit" to change this. Also, please use MathJax:
$\text{\$f: X\to\mathbb R\$}$ will yield $f: X\to\mathbb R$

Comment: thanks, how do I write mathjax on my computer?

Comment: It's implemented in the website (via JavaScript). Just type it down. Most standard $\LaTeX$ code will work

Comment: It's better to ask questions one at a time, and give each one a title that describes what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You should focus especially on the condition $d(x, y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$. You've already characterized what the formula on the left means, but you haven't yet compared it to the one on the right, and said what that means for $f$.

You should indicate that the other conditions to be a metric do not impose any further conditions on $f$. For example, show that the triangle inequality holds for any $f$. It's only the condition mentioned in the first paragraph that makes any difference.

For the second problem, a sequence can converge to at most one value, so only one of the possibilities for $a$ can be correct. Which one is it?

Your third answer looks okay; just be aware of typos (e.g., you want "therefore, $-\inf(S) \geq -s$").